# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una variable de un JFrame a otro?

Tags: java, string, variables, jframe

En el primer `form1.java` tengo esto:

```
if (nickname.getText().equals("")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Error! Ingrese un nombre para continuar.");

} else {
    nombre=nickname.getText();
    juego fr=new juego();
    fr.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
    
}
```

En el `juego.java` tengo esto:

```
form1.nickname.setText(jugador.getText());
```

Esto me da error y no sé el por qué.

Comment: cual es el error que te da?

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar el error en específico que obtienes?

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente de la variable existe una forma de pasar variables.

Ejemplo pasar un entero (Este es solo un ejemplo):

```
public static int enterodeEjemplo;
```

En este caso puedes declarar una variable como `static`.Para usarla en el otro form haces un `import`:

```
import static nombrepaquete.nombredeClase.NombredelMiembroaImportar;
```

Esta instrucción es para importar todos los miembros `static` de una clase:

```
import static nombredelpaquete.nombredeclase.*;
```